# IBM Liberty server 17.0.0.3 - application talks to CICS TG using JCA 1.6, JNDI is not able to lookup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I want to connect my EAR app to CICS via CICS TG in IBM Liberty Server 17.0.0.3. When I try to do that, getting connection factory JNDI name is not found exception.

server.xml

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>...</feature>
    <feature>jca-1.6</feature>
</featureManager>

<connectionFactory id="jcaFactory" jndiName="esi.app.CICS" >
    <properties.jcaResourceAdapter.javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory
            configFile="C:\Temp\jca_config.xml"
     />
</connectionFactory>

<resourceAdapter
        autoStart="true"
        id="jcaResourceAdapter"
        location="jacadapter.rar">
</resourceAdapter>

<application type="ear" id="app" location="app.ear">
    <classloader
            classProviderRef="jcaResourceAdapter" />
</application>
```

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: esi.app.CICS is coming up.

Also, no useful information in messages.log in wlp/usr/myServer/logs directory. Please help me to solve this problem or at least to debug this issue to proceed further. There is no much information in Google as well since I'm trying to use IBM Liberty latest version.

Comment: Include code and full stacktrace?

Comment: You're using the fully qualified ConnectionFactory property name, that's only necessary if the RA specifies more than one ConnectionFactory where neither the simple interface nor the implementation class names are unique, I don't think that's the case for CICSTG RA, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_jca_config_confact.html.  Also, check your CICS RA file name.  Have a look at this blogpost for more insight: https://developer.ibm.com/cics/2014/05/06/using-jca-with-the-cics-tg-in-websphere-liberty-profile/

Comment: @FRowe, Thanks a lot.. it works.. just removed the package name as you said :)